# "Does not meet criteria" when using Jenkins multibranch pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Anyone know why Jenkins multibranch pipeline would refuse to create build branches for my BitBucket repo? A Jenkins file exists in the root of the project, but it simply says "Does not meet criteria" with no real details:

```html
Started by user Nick Smith
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Setting origin to ssh://git@abcabc.com:7999/flex/flex-dataaggregation-service.git
 > git config remote.origin.url ssh://git@abcabc.com:7999/flex/flex-dataaggregation-service.git # timeout=10
Fetching & pruning origin...
Fetching upstream changes from origin
 > git --version # timeout=10
using GIT_SSH to set credentials myteam ssh key
 > git fetch --tags --progress origin +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* --prune
Getting remote branches...
Seen branch in repository origin/bugfix/abc
Seen branch in repository origin/master
Seen 2 remote branches
Checking branch master
Does not meet criteria
Checking branch bugfix/abc
Does not meet criteria
Done.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Thanks

Nick

Comment: You have Jenkinsfile files on those branches?

Comment: Yes I did. It's really weird but it just started working yesterday, with no rhyme nor reason! Thanks the reply anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to fix itself! (see comment above)

Comment: I didn't get the comment. How did you fix it?